# C# ThreadStart VS ProcessStartInfo()

Tags: c#

Good morning,
In my app I use a specific audio recording software  in this way:

```
//OLD CODE

ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
start.Arguments = arguments;
start.FileName = "PROGRAM FOR RECORDING AUDIO";
start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
start.CreateNoWindow = true;

//use timer
runTimer();
using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))
{
     proc.WaitForExit();
}

//Create mp3 and other operations
work();
```

When i quit this program, my app creates mp3 and do other operations. During recording, this program creates file each minute and name them with date and time.
I want to update a listbox present in the app form adding the names of the new mp3 file created. 
To do so I use a timer:

```
public void runTimer()
{
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(RunEvent);
    aTimer.Interval = 10000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;*/

    int timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
    int interval = 10000;
    TimerCallback callback = new TimerCallback(RunEvent);

    System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(callback, null, timeout, interval);
    timer.Change(0, 10000);
}

public void RunEvent(object state)
{
    //search file and update listbox
}
```

But the listbox updates only when the audio recording software is quited.
I changed the old code with the following one:

```
//TEST
Process pr = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo prs = new ProcessStartInfo();
prs.FileName = "PROGRAM FOR RECORDING AUDIO";
pr.StartInfo = prs;

ThreadStart ths = new ThreadStart(delegate() { pr.Start(); });
Thread th = new Thread(ths);
th.Start();
```

In this way the listbox updates properly.
However I do not know how to handle the audio recording software closure in order to use the work() method, present in my old code. Sorry for my bad english ;)

Comment: Have you considered using a File System Watcher? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use async operation. Eg:

```
//use timer
//runTimer(); //Not needed now
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))
    {
        proc.WaitForExit();
    }
    work(); //If you need to wait  the process to finish
});
work(); //If you don't need to wait  the process to finish
```